# Is an image carousel a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to know if an image carousel is a stateful widget or a stateless widget, because if it is stateful, how am I able to create a carousel(image slider) inside a class that extends a stateless class, and the constructor of that class is called inside a stateful widget. I am confused here??

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about carousel slider, yes! it's a stateful widget.

Check this:

```
https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/lib/carousel_slider.dart
```